# HtmlAgilityPack DocumentNode.SelectNodes() не возвращает данные

Tags: c#, htmlagilitypack

Есть страница с резюме (https://ekb.zarplata.ru/resume)
Мне надо выбрать имена и фамилии.
Открыл код через f12, нашел соответствующие имена и фамилиям место в html коде.
Скопировал XPath.

Далее, есть следующий C# код:

```
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        var doc = web.Load("https://ekb.zarplata.ru/resume");
        var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"app\"]//div//div//div//div//div//div//div//div//div//div//div//div//div//div//div//div//div//div//span");
```

В `SelectNodes` я вставил как раз то, что скопировал в XPath. Только поставил экранирование там где нужно. Но в итоге переменная `node` у меня равна `null`. А в ней должны бы лежать имена и фамилии из резюме.

Comment: Коллекция пустая, потому что резюме прогружаются позже через AJAX-запрос. Соответственно у Вас же в `doc` будет лежать исходный код страницы сайта без резюме.

Comment: @maxwell, я смотрел пример, там она была не пустая и без AJAX-запрос. И в любом случае, что мне сделать, что бы она была не пустая?

Comment: Как вариант отлавливать ссылки на AJAX-запросы и делать GET-запросы уже по этим ссылкам или же использовать компонент браузера, в котором ожидать полной прогрузки страницы.

Comment: Попробуйте [AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp). С ним вроде не должно быть проблемы.

Comment: @maxwell, вы безусловно правы) а у меня опыта в этом деле совсем нет. Поэтому даже не понимаю с чего подступиться к этой проблеме. Как отлавливать ссылки на AJAX-запросы? Как использовать компонент браузера, в котором ожидать полной прогрузки страницы?

Comment: @maxwell, можете хоть направление указать? Что читать, куда лезть?

Comment: Вам нужно получить полностью загруженную HTML-страницу с  выполненными скриптами и AJAX-запросами. Так и гуглите. К примеру, вот: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169484/htmlagilitypack-and-dynamic-content-issue